# How do I refresh page data to display dynamic table data that was altered with an ajax call without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got an ajax call that changes, at the moment just the first name for testing purposes, of a contact using a bootstrap modal. On success I want the page data refreshed, but not to actually reload the page. So once the user clicks save changes the modal disappears and the table data with refresh with newly changed name. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test');

require_once 'Model.php';
require_once 'Contact.php';

$contacts = Contact::find_all();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                var clicked = this.id;

                $.ajax({
                    url:      'edit.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        action: "display",
                        id: this.id
                    },
                    success:  function(data) {
                        $("#fname").val(data.first_name);

                        $("#save").click(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url:      'edit.php',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {
                                    action: "save",
                                    id: clicked,
                                    first_name: $("#fname").val()
                                },
                                success:  function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                    //refresh page here
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($contacts as $contact): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $contact->first_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact->last_name ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact->email ?></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="" id="<?php echo $contact->id ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                    Edit Contact
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary save" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can probably tell I am very new to AJAX and JS/jQuery.

Comment: when you get the name from the AJAX call back from your back-end script, you just simple verify it's a correct call back, then insert it into the document using `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: How would I be able to insert to the appropriate ID? I tried `$("#first_name" + clicked).html(data.first_name);` and named the first name `<td>` as `<td id="first_name<?php echo $contact->id ?>">` but after one update when you click on another button without refreshing the page it will take the id of the newly clicked button, and the old button(s) and will therefore edit all buttons clicked in the session. Basically it updates all names, not just one. I've only just realised that my code isn't working properly because it's updating the names of all id's when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the table "on the fly" one data is back from AJAX call - which happens on the callback function specified in success option on $.ajax() call.
Right now you simply show the data coming back on a console.
You need to clear what is in your  (by calling e.g. `$('tbody').html('')` ) and then basing on the data that is in "data" parameter create the approriate structure of a table inside...
Helpful methods you might want to look for in JQuery docs might be:

```
.each()
.append()
.html()
```

Hope the above helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggest reading :) however, my main problem now is that my ajax call is being fired for every button clicked including previous ones. So if I update more than first name without reloading the page all the names will be updated to the same most recently updated name. Should I create a separate question for this? I feel like it's because I'm firing the ajax call after a button element is clicked when I should target the ID, but I wouldn't know what to call the ID of each separate button that creates the modal as they are dynamic :/

Comment: That is becouse you are attaching yje function of calling the AJAX query to every "button" element on your page.
Instead you should think of attaching that event only to specific buttons, potentially add some additional HTML attributes to your buttons (e.g. with user ID) and then access there attribs with `$('button').attr('id')` to modify the call that is made in AJAX